# Using both activeTab and serial permissions

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I am trying to use a hardware serial device to change what displays on a webpage in Chrome. I'm making a Chrome extension to do so, however it seems as if I cannot use both the `activeTab` and `serial` permissions at the same time. The `activeTab` permission requires the app to not be a packaged app, and the `serial` permission requires the app to be packaged.

How can I get around this if possible?

I am using the [page redder](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples) sample code as the way to change the webpage, however it requires the `activeTab` permission. Maybe there is a workaround to this? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way I can think of is to create one Chrome Extension and one Chrome App that communicates to each other: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external

```js
// The ID of the extension we want to talk to.
var laserExtensionId = "abcdefghijklmnoabcdefhijklmnoabc";

// Make a simple request:
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(laserExtensionId, {getTargetData: true},
  function(response) {
    if (targetInRange(response.targetData))
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage(laserExtensionId, {activateLasers: true});
  });

// Start a long-running conversation:
var port = chrome.runtime.connect(laserExtensionId);
port.postMessage(...);
```

Comment: Thanks, I used this method and it was successful!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to make a [Native Messaging host](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#native-messaging) that communicates with the device and with your extension.

From architectural point of view this makes more sense, but limits your deployment options, as the host program can't be bundled with the extension in the Web Store.